# Can't access the object properties in child page Bootstrap Tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've bumped into a strange situation with **ui bootraps Tab** that i cannot access the object properties though it shows full content correctly.

Controller fixtureLiveFormation:

```
    $scope.statsTabs = [
             { heading: 'Team Stats', route: 'livematch.teamstats', template: '/App/Main/views/dulieu1trandau/report_teamstats.html', active: true },
             { heading: 'Player Stats', route: 'livematch.playerstats', template: '/App/Main/views/dulieu1trandau/report_playerstats.html' }
    ];
    $scope.changeTab = function (route) {
        switch (route) {
            case 'livematch.teamstats':   
                break;
            case 'livematch.playerstats':
dataService.getleagueplayerstats($scope.pagingInfo).then(function (data) {
                    $scope.playerStats = _.filter(data.results, function (item) { return item.PlayerId == 90 });                    
                }); 
                 break;
    <tabset>
```

View:

```
<section ng-controller="fixtureLiveFormation">
      <tab ng-repeat="t in statsTabs" heading="{{t.heading}}" active="t.active" disabled="t.disabled" ng-click="changeTab(t.route)">
           <div ng-include="t.template"></div>
            </tab>
    </tabset>
</section>
```

On report_playerstats.html

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
           {{playerStats.Name}}  => show nothing but

{{playerStats}} -> show 

[{"PlayerId":90,"TeamOwnerId":4,"Name":"Aaron Ramsey","Team":"Arsenal"...}]
</div>
```

Why it could happen that way, please give me some advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this happens because your `_.filter()` method returns array of players and not a single player. Just amend your code as follows:

```
...
$scope.playerStats = _.filter(data.results, function (item) { return item.PlayerId == 90 })[0];
...
```

You can add some checks that filtered array contains items.